# How to find lines which are beginning from #, with exceptions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've C++ file, like:

```
#include <stdio>
#if 0
int a=1;
#endif
.....
```

How to write regular expression to find all lines which are beginning from #, except the lines which are starting from the #include keyword?

Comment: Is that [javascript] tag there because you're using JavaScript regex to search the file?

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
/^#(?!include).*$/gm
```

Comment: Our answers aren't exactly the same, so you need to make up your mind which **exactly** you need...

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\s*#(?!include\b).*$/m
```

matches a line that starts with optional whitespace, then a `#`, unless followed by `include`.

So, in JavaScript:

```
result = subject.match(/^\s*#(?!include\b).*$/mg);
```

Comment: If you are wondering what this `?!` business is: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Be aware that your matches will include any blank/empty lines that happen to precede the target line.  If that isn't your intent, you might want to change the `\s*` to `[ \t]*`.